# Drop a file to a folder on Adobe Acrobat DC Pro

Tags: icon, adobe-acrobat, copy-and-paste

Most of the applications I use have a little trick to drop the opened files into a folder:
Drag the mini icon at the header and move it to the destination window.

[image: Word with a mini icon on top]

However, the new version of Adobe Acrobat doesn't seem to have this feature.

[image: Adobe Acrobat DC]

Does anyone know how to quickly drop the file I've opened to a folder in a similar way?

The version I'm using is this:

Architecture: x86_64
Processor: Intel
Build: 22.2.20212.0
AGM: 4.30.120
CoolType: 6.2.4
JP2K: 2.0.6.50420